# How to get IEnumerable enum from bool values?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, ienumerable

I have below code snippet. I wanted GetPermissions method in such a way that i will get only those enums which has item.Actions.XXXX.value =true

Earlier i was using dictionary so code which i have commented was working

```
public class ResourcePermissionModel
    {
        public ResourcePermissionModel();
        public int ResourceId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    }

 public enum Permission
    {
        View = 0,
        Modify = 1,
        Delete = 2,
        Assign = 3
    }

var resourcePerm= result.RoleAccess.Permissions
    .Select(item => new ResourcePermissionModel()
    {
        ResourceId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Id),
        Permissions = GetPermissions(item.Actions)
        //Permissions = new Dictionary<LockboxService.Models.Enum.Permission, bool>
        //{
        //    { LockboxService.Models.Enum.Permission.Assign, item.Actions.Assign.Value },
        //    { LockboxService.Models.Enum.Permission.Delete, item.Actions.Delete.Value },
        //    { LockboxService.Models.Enum.Permission.Modify, item.Actions.Modify.Value },
        //    { LockboxService.Models.Enum.Permission.View, item.Actions.Use.Value }
        //}
    }).ToList();
private IEnumerable<Permission> GetPermissions(ResourceActionsBase actions)
{
//what to enter here?
}
```

Comment: can you please explain the structure of ResourceActionsBase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use yield return:

```
private IEnumerable<Permission> GetPermissions(ResourceActionsBase actions)
{
    if (actions.Use.Value)
        yield return Permission.View;
    if (actions.Modify.Value)
        yield return Permission.Modify;
    if (actions.Delete.Value)
        yield return Permission.Delete;
    if (actions.Assign.Value)
        yield return Permission.Assign;
}
```

You might want to add `ToList()` after the call to `GetPermissions` or else it will execute deferred everytime you get the `Permissions` from your `ResourcePermissionModel`.

Also please note, that I think this approach scales badly if you add more permissions. In that case it might be useful if you can actually change the model or use a static mapping from the model properties to the Permission-Values

Comment: Thanks . Could you Please elaborate a bit on static mapping from model